# Dropdown in Gridview Template jQuery call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET gridview within which i have a template column which hosts a dropdown. the dropdown is bound from server side code. I am attaching the following JavaScript:

```
dl.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return UpdateTaskDetail(" + dl.ClientID +  ",'" + u.TaskID + "','" + "');");
```

I am able to execute the JavaScript function name UpdateTaskDetail.

The issue in want to get the selected value of the dropdown for which i have been trying the following

```
 var taskstatusid = $("#" + ctr.name + " option:selected").val();
```

This line does not fetch the value.

Can someone please tell me what might be incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

In your UpdateTaskDetail function you can do something like this:

```
function UpdateTaskDetail(control, task, other ){
    var taskstatusidVal = $("#" + control).val();//For selected value. remove "option:selected"
    var taskstatusidText = $("#" + control + " option:selected").text();//For selected Text
    alert(taskstatusidVal + taskstatusidText);//Test    
}
```